# How to expand two items in Graph API

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I want to get a user's direct reports, and photo in graph api. If I try:

```
var users = await graphClient.Users.Request().Expand("DirectReports", "Photo").GetAsync();
```

I get an error saying that the Expand method doesn't take two arguments. I have tried the below:

```
var users = await graphClient.Users.Request().Expand("DirectReports", "Photo").GetAsync();
var users = await graphClient.Users.Request().Expand("DirectReports;Photo").GetAsync();
var users = await graphClient.Users.Request().Expand("DirectReports").Expand("Photo").GetAsync();
```

But they don't work either. Is there any way to use two expands? or is there a workaround that would allow me to get both the Photo and Direct Reports of every user with just one call?

Comment: Hi, if the posted answer resolves your question, please mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark. Doing so helps others find answers to their questions. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#expand-parameter) you can use expand on only one single RelationShip.

> You can use the $expand query string parameter to include the expanded
> resource or collection referenced by a single relationship (navigation
> property) in your results.

And expanding the photo is also no supported as of now. Its documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#expand-parameter).

> Note: Not all relationships and resources support the $expand query
> parameter. For example, you can expand the directReports, manager, and
> memberOf relationships on a user, but you cannot expand its events,
> messages, or photo relationships. Not all resources or relationships
> support using $select on expanded items.

If you want to expand 2 supported relationships at a time you should make 2 separate HTTP requests with different expand relationships and using the user id's you can pick them.

Comment: Is it possible to get the photo of every user with just one call?

Comment: You can try [JSON Batching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/json-batching) which combine multiple requests in one HTTP call.